# Placement of a plumbing cleanout

Tags: plumbing

We attached a PVC pipe to our main drain in the basement. We ran it along the basement wall and outside underground and a cleanout was placed.

Is there any code out that would keep us from passing a home inspection?

Comment: Can you provide a sketch of what was done with the cleanout and piping including any critical dimensions? This will be of great help in providing the most useful answer.

Comment: Click the [edit] button to include some pics (clear and focused, overall and some details) and the sketch (doesn't have to be to scale, just include dimensions) mentioned above.

Comment: Why did you put the clean out so far away and underground outside?  Is the PVC pipe solely for the clean out?  More info is needed.